# Fullpage.js some slides fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

Is it possible to have some slides of a page using fullpage.js scroll and some  fade in in the same page?

For example, the first three sections should scroll normally and then three should fade in and then the last one should again go back to scrolling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fullpage.js Using a custom transition on one certain section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599795/fullpage-js-using-a-custom-transition-on-one-certain-section)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [fading extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/fadingEffect.html) to create the fading effect for your sections or slides.

Then, you can turn it off or on in any callback or under any event you want by calling:

```
$.fn.fullpage.fadingEffect.turnOn();
$.fn.fullpage.fadingEffect.turnOff();
```

As can be seen in that same demo page.